# Dataframe getting list of values between two row locations where index is of type datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, `df` of datetime index:

```
               Date    X
2020-01-01 00:00:00  1.1
2020-01-01 00:15:00  1.2
2020-01-01 00:30:00  1.3
2020-01-01 00:45:00  1.4
2020-01-01 01:00:00  1.5
```

How can I get the values between, say, the 2nd and the 4th rows as a list:

```
values = [1.2, 1.3, 1.4]
```

I am aware that I can do this:

```
values = []
for i in range(1,3):
    values.append(df.iloc[i]["X"])
```

But I am looking for an elegant solution.

Comment: `list(df.iloc[1,3]['x'])`?

Comment: Is `Date` a column or is it the index?

Comment: @wwii it is an index, I updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `iloc` and `tolist`

```
 df.iloc[1:4, df.columns.get_loc('X')].tolist()

 Out[670]: [1.2, 1.3, 1.4]
```